# C#.net getting error:- Failed to allocate memory for custom tag binary object (930513672 elements of 1)

Tags: c#, imagemagick

We are getting the following error when Uploading 934mb tif file:

> Failed to allocate memory for custom tag binary object (930513672 elements of 1 in .

my web Config settings are :-

```
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="6000000" maxRequestLength="5242880" useFullyQualifiedRedirectUrl="false" minFreeThreads="8" minLocalRequestFreeThreads="4" requestValidationMode="2.0" appRequestQueueLimit="100" enableVersionHeader="true" /> 
<system.webServer>
```

MagickCode:

```
StringBuilder ext = new StringBuilder();
ext.Append( Path.GetExtension(destination_path));

MagickReadSettings setting = new MagickReadSettings();
setting.Density = new Density(20, 20);
setting.ColorSpace = ColorSpace.RGB;

using (MagickImage first = new MagickImage(filetoconvert, setting))
{
    first.Quality = 300;
    first.Trim();
    first.Write(destination_path);
    first.Dispose();
}

<security>
  <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483648" />
  </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

Comment: this is exception throwing by the library not c#/clr

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like your issue is related to the upload of the file, so the maxAllowedContentLength etc doesn't really matter. The error is in hydrating the image to a MagickImage?

I was having basically the same problem, but with a much smaller .TIFF file (< 200MB). I had some issues with the way I was disposing the MagickImage, and when I resolved those, the error I got was TIFF error 572. I had a brief exchange with Dirk Lemstra, and he pointed me to build settings.

My code was building to Any CPU, but Prefer 32 Bit was turned on. Turning that off, or building to x64 resolved my issue. I was tripped up by IIS Express failing in debug mode, by default IIS Express runs in 32bit, you need to enable it in Visual Studio (Tools - Options - Projects and Solutions).

Thanks